# Proof for finitely additive set function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let a denote the class of all subsets of a given universal set. Let f be a finitely additive set function defined on class a. Let there exist arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$ that are part of the class a.

Trying to prove: $f(A \cap B') = f(A \cup B) - f(B)$.

I was able to prove this for a different question given the finitely additive set function that counts the elements of finite sets. For example, given a set with 5 elements, the function outputs 5. However, now the function is not given to us and how can I prove this generally.

I thought that $B$ is a subset of $A \cup B$ would be needed to prove this statement. I figured out that $(A \cup B) - B = A \cap B'$. This doesn't prove that the set difference is the same as the difference of sets however.

Comment: $A\cup B$ is the disjoint union of $A\cap B'$ and $B$. I cannot see what stops you.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed to complete the proof.